# How to send an FCM message to more than 5 topics?

Tags: push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

The Cloud Messaging docs mention a limit of 5 topics when sending a message (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging). This seems ridiculously low which makes me think that my use case isn't intended to be solved by using topics.

Users can subscribe to weather alerts for anywhere between 1 and 26 counties. Weather alerts can apply to more than one county. I thought I could have users subscribe to a topic for each county then send an FCM message to the topics applicable to that alert's counties.

Can I even achieve this with Cloud Messaging? Do I need to store user's counties in Firestore along with their registration token and then send the messages to all the applicable registration token's instead?

Comment: `You can include up to five topics in your conditional expression.` -- its for the conditional expression. If you want to send a message to all your topics (without any  condition) then just send them as is like a regular message. Devices subscribed to the topic(s) will receive them regularly.

Comment: @AL. Are you saying there's a way to send a message to a list of topics outside of the conditional expression? I can't find any mention of that in the docs.

Comment: You mentioned that the topics were used for weather notifications from different locations -- I assume that no same topic would send the same notification. Why not send the notifications separately for each topic? Or am I missing a use case?

Comment: I think the problem is that the notifications can apply to more than one location. I can send the notification once for each location but then users who are subscribed to multiple locations might get duplicated notifications.

Comment: @ChrisO Have you figured out a solution yet? I have been scratching my head for like a year and still couldn't figure out a good solution. I can think of two options right now: 1. stop using topics and send directly to devices 2. When one message has more than five topics, just send to the most important 5 topics. Both of the solutions are not ideal.

Comment: @OliverZhang I was forced to handle the device tokens myself and write my own sending logic to individual devices. It was a pain to set up but it works quite well. When a user sign up for notifications i save their fcm token in firestore alone with a list of their sending options. Then I can get a list of fcm tokens to send a notification to and process them one by one.

Comment: @ChrisO Thanks. I guess that's the way to go eventually.